# List Comprehension to remove unwanted objects. Validating it works as expected

Tags: python, list, validation, list-comprehension

I'm using Python 3. I am trying to remove certain lists from a list of lists. I found an excellent article that explained how to do that using list comprehension. It appears to work as expected, but it got me thinking ... In my original efforts I was appending any list object that was to be deleted to a new list. I could then actually look at these objects and assure myself the right ones were being removed. With the comprehension method I can only "see" the ones that remain. Is there a way of "seeing" what's "failed" the list comprehension condition? It would be reassuring to know that only the correct objects gave been removed.

Comment: found answer by mistake ... simply temporarily invert logic ... this will "keep" what will be deleted with non-inverted logic. check happy with results, then revert logic back.

Comment: (Got me think "split"…)

Comment: (Note that you are welcome to answer your own question (if you think both question and answer useful). There even is a [badge for well-received self-answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/14/self-learner).

Answer (score 0):

I actually managed to answer my own question by making a mistake. To see what will be removed from a list by the list comprehension, simply temporarily invert the condition logic. This will allow you to look at all the elements that will be removed. If you're happy that the removals are as you expect, then simply re-invert the logic again, back to original and execute.